# py2app tkinter 'Detected missing constraints' error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, py2app

I am trying to package an existing python script that uses tk to choose a file and ask for a value into an app that includes all the dependencies.

I am using MacOS 10.12.5, homebrew python 3.6.1 and py2app 0.14.

The following works fine as a script, but when converted to an app (or -A alias app) I get an error `Detected missing constraints for <private>...` on the console.  Simplified version that still produces the same error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

the_answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What is the answer?",)
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?  If it is a bug is it a tk or py2app bug?

Comment: Raised a py2app bug [link](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/232/py2app-tk-app-fails-with-detected-missing)